# Hibernate Criteria.list() issues an "ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column" error

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm executing a Hibernate `Criteria.list()` and getting the error:

> ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column.

**Edit:**

Really the problem was on the Oracle. Among the parameters existing on database Oracle, there is one NLS_SORT that works like this:

```
NLS_SORT=WEST_EUROPEAN; //limits the clause 'order by' for a column that not exceed 999 characters
```

or

```
NLS_SORT=BINARY; //accepts values greater than 999 characters on the clause 'order by'
```

I was passing a column that did contain more than 999 characters on the clause 'order by'. For more information, click [link1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn10127.htm#REFRN10127) and [link2](http://www.serkey.com/ora-01401-when-using-order-by-clause-on-oracle-xe-western-european-bdzu6r.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate's session acts like a cache and entity writes are persisted to the database only at the last possible moment or when the session is flushed.

My guess is that `list()` triggers inserts or updates into the database from some previously modified entities. It does this because Hibernate needs to guarantee that the `list()` will never return stale or incorrect data.

[Log the queries Hibernate generates](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) (`hibernate.show_sql` + `hibernate.format_sql`) and see what particular statement is executed before the error.